# How to loop through an 2 Dimension array in a logic app?

Tags: logic

I have create a 2D object

```
{"body":[{"id":"%7B78949B86-1DFE-4025-84CC-1C736339D89A%7D","name":"MTL"},{"id":"%7BD74F4070-69F3-45AF-B9A0-410445562825%7D","name":"KKMT"}]}
```

and i want to loop using for each in logic app.

I have create a logic app but not able to loop in there not sure where i am going wrong

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek05f.png)

Comment: In for loop I am not able to retrieve all the values and not getting any data like id and name for each loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a logic app for your requirement. It should be as below.
[image: Here is the designer view]

Here is how you can go through the JSON file and use it in the For-each loop.

[image: Output]

Let me know if you have questions. If this is helpful, mark as answer.